# PowerShell Core message of the day on Linux platforms

Tags: powershell

Where does the message of the day come from on Linux-like OSes for PowerShell Core?

As it was [confirmed](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/pull/4132#issuecomment-317335669), on Windows it comes from `$PSHOME\Microsoft.PowerShell_profile.ps1` but this file does not exist on Ubuntu, yet I still see the usual message.

**Edit:** the issue I referenced shows that in the Windows version, the greeting that shows up when launching PS6 comes from the system profile, that's where we could disable the (now obsolete) warning of including PS5 module paths by default.

```
PowerShell v6.0.0
Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

https://aka.ms/pscore6-docs
Type 'help' to get help.

Loading personal and system profiles took 1139ms.
```

This is all the default *bloat* one gets when opening a PS console. I would like to have some control over what I see here, I just can't seem to find the origin of these messages.

The only reference I found to the help string (which is the most useless one) is found in an XML note that references a the same binary that grep founds, as if the message originated from a binary, and hence is hardcoded.

```
grep -r "https://aka.ms/pscore6-docs" /opt/microsoft/
Binary file /opt/microsoft/powershell/6.0.0-rc.2/Microsoft.PowerShell.ConsoleHost.dll matches
/opt/microsoft/powershell/6.0.0-rc.2/Microsoft.PowerShell.ConsoleHost.xml:            https://aka.ms/pscore6-docs
```

Can it be that this message is hardcoded?

Comment: The GitHub issue you reference has zero mentions of the "message of the day"

Comment: Check all scripts listed in `($profile | get-member -type noteproperty).Definition`

Comment: There is no "message of the day" native to PowerShell Core on any platform. You have something in/on the system outputting that information. Adding a screenshot showing what you are talking about may help provide a better reference as well.

Comment: Thanks @JosefZ for the tip, did not know that trick (still don't know how that property manifests). The 4 scripts it lists don't exist, apart from /home/mnagy/.config/powershell/Microsoft.PowerShell_profile.ps1

Comment: Could `powershell -NoLogo` help? (I can't know being on Windows 10/PS 5.1).

Comment: Indeed, Nologo helps. I think I'll work with that. I'll try to update the post once I find a definitive answer.